# Create PL/SQL WatchDog/Daemon in Oracle 11gr2

Tags: oracle, plsql

I should create a watchdog that monitor a field in a table every 5 minutes, in Oracle DB. If field has a specific value (a date older than x) an action should be performed.
Is it possible to do it in PL/SQL?

If it's not, I should create a script shell and call it from crontab, or maybe use the Scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

> If field has a specific value (a date older than x) an action should be performed.

You could create a **TRIGGER**. If a new row is inserted such that the date column has a specific value, then you perform some action in the trigger.

Perhaps, you need an `AFTER INSERT TRIGGER FOR EACH ROW`, since you need to reference the `:NEW` values.

Here is the link to documentation regarding [CREATE TRIGGER](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_trigger.htm#LNPLS01374).

If you really want to do it as a scheduled job, then you could use **DBMS_SCHEDULER**. Prior to 10g releases, it was **DBMS_JOB**.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use the [DBMS_SCHEDULER package](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_sched.htm#CIHHBGGI%20DBMS_SCHEDULER%20package)

> The DBMS_SCHEDULER package provides a collection of scheduling functions and procedures that are callable from any PL/SQL program. (...)
>   The Scheduler uses a rich calendaring syntax to enable you to define repeating schedules, such as "every Tuesday and Friday at 4:00 p.m." or "the second Wednesday of every month."

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, maybe I've omitted a detail the field to monitor is for a specific row. I mean if the result of the query: 
select up_date from mytab where name_id='test'
is older than 15minutes
then 
update mytab set value_col='no' where name_id='test'

But I don't know if it's possible to do it with a trigger. With SCHEDULER I could check at interval time and could be a good work-around.

Answer (score 0):

You may still have a AFTER UPDATE trigger and in that trigger check if the updated row is the one you want to watch. Something like this:

`IF :old.name_id = 'test' THEN
   -- do something here
END IF;`